# NameError: uninitialized constant Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, sanitize

About three hours ago I started seeing the above error in my production server. It comes from a call to the sanitize gem:

```
vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/../../activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:276:in 'load_missing_constant'
vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/../../activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `const_missing'
vendor/gems/sanitize-1.2.0/lib/sanitize.rb:91:in `clean!'
vendor/gems/sanitize-1.2.0/lib/sanitize.rb:84:in `clean'
vendor/gems/sanitize-1.2.0/lib/sanitize.rb:49:in `clean'   
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:28:in `display_none'
app/views/main/_blogs.html.erb:13:in `_run_erb_47app47views47main47_blogs46html46erb'
```

The error only occurs on the production server (linux), not my development machine (windows)

I tried rolling back my latest deployment but it didn't fix it.

I've updated to sanitize 1.2.0 (which was the latest version brought down by `gem update sanitize`, though I note my host is running 1.3.6.

Can anyone provide any clues to help fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downgrading to '1.0.8'. See the [history](http://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/blob/master/HISTORY#L29-34) and note the switch to using Nokogiri. If this fixes the issue, ensure you have the latest version of Sanitize, Nokogiri 1.4.1 and libxml2 2.7.2 installed.